# isolate data from a string

Tags: python, string

The string below gets printed in my 3d application and it is position data for geometries:

( (1, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)  (0, 0, 1)  (0, 0, 0)),( (1, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)  (0, 0, 1)  (-38.805, 0, 1333.283)),( (1, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)  (0, 0, 1)  (-77.609, 0, 2666.566)),( (1, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)  (0, 0, 1)  (-116.414, 0, 3999.849)),( (1, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)  (0, 0, 1)  (-155.218, 0, 5333.133))...

I only want the string to print the following:
(0, 0, 0),(-38.805, 0, 1333.283),(-77.609, 0, 2666.566),(-116.414, 0, 3999.849),(-155.218, 0, 5333.133)...

Comment: Have you looked at your question, and read it? How do you expect anyone to go through that? Make a minimal example which shows your problem, please.

Comment: Can you post exactly what you'd like the result to be? Do you have to use Python code? Can you use a regular expression?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean b y, data associated with "off"? Do you meen from "off" until the next ";", or the next ",". Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: okay so i just want the string to print the following:  (-38.805, 0, 1333.283),(-77.609, 0, 2666.566),(-116.414, 0, 3999.849),(-116.414, 0, 3999.849) not any of the (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) which repeats

Comment: There is also an "off: (0, 0, 0))", do you want that in the output? It would be really helpful if you could change/update your answer, so that is is more clear and has the exact output you want for the input you give. Also, why are you using a string for this? It seems like you would be much better off using some form of a list/dictionary.

Comment: yes (0,0,0) is the position for the first polygon, i need that to remain. i've edited my initial question, hope it is better than my first attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
inp = "((Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (0, 0, 0)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-38.805, 0, 1333.283)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-77.609, 0, 2666.566)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-116.414, 0, 3999.849)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-155.218, 0, 5333.133)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-194.023, 0, 6666.416)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0) ; v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-232.827, 0, 7999.699)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-271.632, 0, 9332.982)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-310.436, 0, 10666.265)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-349.241, 0, 11999.548)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-388.045, 0, 13332.832)),Matrix(v1: (1, 0, 0); v2: (0, 1, 0); v3: (0, 0, 1); off: (-426.85, 0, 14666.115))"

lst = inp.split(";")
for s in lst:
    s.strip()
    if s.find("off:") > -1:
        data = s.split(")")
        print(data[0][7:])
```

will produce:

```
0, 0, 0
-38.805, 0, 1333.283
-77.609, 0, 2666.566
-116.414, 0, 3999.849
-155.218, 0, 5333.133
-194.023, 0, 6666.416
-232.827, 0, 7999.699
-271.632, 0, 9332.982
-310.436, 0, 10666.265
-349.241, 0, 11999.548
-388.045, 0, 13332.832
-426.85, 0, 14666.115
```

**Note:** I did not use list comprehension or generators - to make the code as plain as possible.

Comment: Thanks alot Boardrider :)